About kernel, Green functions.
Consider the heat equation
\begin{align}
\partial_t u(t,x)&=\Delta u(t,x),\quad t>0,\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n\\
u(0,x)&=u_0(x)
\end{align}
The Green function (or kernel) is $G_t(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathrm{e}^{ix\cdot \xi}\mathrm{e}^{-t |\xi|^2}\,d\xi$. This kernel is good in the sense that, for all $t>0,\, \left\|G_t\right\|_{L^1}=C$, a constant (independent of $t$).
If only have that $K_t(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathrm{e}^{ix\cdot \xi}\mathrm{e}^{-t F(|\xi|^2)}\,d\xi$ (another kernel with $F$ some function). Is there some (usual maybe) trick for obtain that $\left\|K_t\right\|_{L^1}=C$ another constant independent of the time $t$?

The function $\xi \mapsto |\xi|^2$ is $2$-homogeneous, if $F$ also have this property you can do the same trick, if not, probably is not easy to prove and I think it must be false in general
